# How to tether with a Blackberry 9000 via bluetooth?

Tags: 10.10, bluetooth, smartphone, tether

How do I tether my Ubuntu 10.10 via Bluetooth with Blackberry 9000? I set everything up and tried to connect, but it keeps asking me for the password. I don't know what password it wants.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please specify the steps you used to tether. Screenshot of the password prompt will be helpful too.

Answer (score 2):

If it asks for a Pin (maybe they named it password) while you are setting up the bluetooth connection: Just enter a 4 digit number (like 0000). Bluetooth requires you to authenticate a new connection by entering the same Pin on both devices to ensure that you really have access to both devices.

If it asks after you have made the bluetooth connection: Sorry, no clue ;)